# SDL Web8.5 loading error in /WebUI/Core/Services/Communicator.svc/Invoke failed to execute. STATUS (404): Not Found

Tags: web8, sdl-tridion

Yesterday we installed SDL Web 8.5 and try to login CME. I got error.

/WebUI/Core/Services/Communicator.svc/Invoke failed to execute. STATUS (404): Not Found

Any one have idea how to resolve this issue.

[image]

Comment: I think we will need (much) more info than this. I also installed 8.5 this morning, and I _don't_ get this error. - Was it an upgrade? Any errors logged in the Windows Event logs? Have you tried turning on Tracing? Any errors logged in the browser console?

Comment: Yes Nuno, it`s upgrade sdl web 8.1 to sdl web 8.5

Answer (score 3):

We just had a similar case after installation of 8.5 - all svc services were returning 404.
It turned out that there were no Handler Mappings in IIS for *.svc so we had to add "HTTP Activation" for .NET Framework 4.6 WCF Services (Server Manager > Add Roles and Features > Features).

[image: HTTP Activation]

Comment: wcf activation enabled?

Comment: @SudhakarRao 
Please see the screenshot I added to the answer.
This is on Windows Server 2016.